# centre text in bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

How do I set the width of the links in my nav bar (including the brand name) so that it's 960px wide and centred within the page? I still want the background of the navbar to stretch the full width of the browser and also still want my responsive button to work when collapsing down.

I've tried various methods but can't seem to get it to work. Do I need to seperate out the background of the nav bar from the text and centre it somehow?

Here is my HTML mark up:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- row 1: navigation -->
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#"class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    
            target="#collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: you try text-align:center;?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to your navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom" role="navigation">
```

And the following CSS definition:

```
.navbar-custom {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: That has centred the text at a 960px width but the background of the nav bar isn't stretching the full width of the browser and the responsive elements have stopped working. Should I try putting a navbar-inner class and customise that?

Comment: Worth a try! Let us know how you get on.

Comment: I've added the class and added a width of 100% to the navbar-inner but I think it's applying this to whole of the nav bar so the text has gone back to how it was.

Comment: Is there a way of separating out the background of the navbar and the links without messing up the responsive elements?

Comment: Put what you have into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and append the link to your question.

Comment: not sure if I've done this right but here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/QzQPR/2/

Comment: Have a look at my modification to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/QzQPR/5/

Comment: Not sure that's done it. The logo looks to be in the middle of the page and there are no links anymore??